# Cannot restore dump file to Compose for MySQL instance

Tags: mysql, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am currently working on migrating my client from AWS to IBM Cloud and I've created a Compose for MySQL instance. I created a dump file from the MySQL instance hosted on AWS and am trying to restore it on Compose for MySQL but I am receiving the following errors:

> If I try to restore the structure only, I receive this error: "ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 313: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation". When I looked at line 313 in the dump file, it is attempting to create a stored procedure, so apparently my admin account does not have permissions to create stored procedures.

However:

> If I try to restore a dump file with structure and data, I receive this error: "the table does not conform to the requirements of an external plugin". This error happens after the first table is created and the INSERT statement is attempting to restore the data to this table.

I am attempting to restore these dump files using MySQL Workbench connected to my Compose for MySQL instance. How can I restore one of these dump files (ideally the one with structure and data) to my Compose for MySQL instance?